# how to control directory name inside zip file created by python sdist

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following setup.py package properties in my setup.py file.

```
setup(
    name='my-project',
    version='1.0,
    author='self',
    author_email='myid@mydomain.com',
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=glob.glob('./*.py'),
)
```

when i do python ./setup.py sdist --format=zip it creates my-project-1.0.zip and inside that the directory structure is as follows

```
my-project-1.0
    myfile.py
```

when i create lambda using the zip file, the version is giving me troubles. The period in 1.0 of the folder name is coming out as 1/0 How can i control the directory inside zip file and make it look like just my-project instead of my-project-1.0